# I am trying to build an android app using dreamweaver cs5.5 in windows 10 laptop

Tags: android, windows-10, dreamweaver, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to build an Android app using dreamweaver cs5.5 in windows 10 laptop. I am facing an error during building and emulating my code in dreamweaver. I installed java jdk 1.8 in to my system, and I also installed the SDK with android N preview and all the necessary build tools, but when I select the build and emulate button after I finished coding a new window pops out saying "building". After 10 seconds or more the window disappears without any message. When I checked the buildinglog file I saw the message saying:

```
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\EDEN\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Users\EDEN\AppData\Local\Android\ANDROI~1\PLATFO~2
C:\Users\EDEN\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
____________________
</DW>
List of devices attached



Launching the Android emulator
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\EDEN\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Users\EDEN\AppData\Local\Android\ANDROI~1\tools
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /u /c "C:\Users\EDEN\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe -partition-size 1024 -cpu-delay 0 -no-boot-anim -avd avd"
____________________
</DW>

<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\EDEN\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Users\EDEN\Desktop\ORGFAN~1.REM
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /u /c C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1\bin\ant.bat debug
____________________
</DW>
Buildfile: C:\Users\EDEN\Desktop\ORGFAN~1.REM\build.xml



-set-mode-check:



-set-debug-files:



-check-env:

 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.4.1

 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\EDEN\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk



-setup:

     [echo] Project Name: remedies

  [gettype] Project Type: Application



-set-debug-mode:



-debug-obfuscation-check:



-pre-build:



-build-setup:

[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 23.0.3

     [echo] Resolving Build Target for remedies...

[gettarget] Project Target:   Android N (Preview)

[gettarget] API level:        N

    [echo] ----------

     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...

    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\EDEN\Desktop\ORGFAN~1.REM\bin\rsObj

    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\EDEN\Desktop\ORGFAN~1.REM\bin\rsLibs

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for remedies...

[dependency] Library dependencies:

[dependency] No Libraries

[dependency] 

[dependency] ------------------

 [echo] ----------

 [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

[subant] No sub-builds to iterate on



-code-gen:

[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File

[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.

[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.

     [echo] Handling aidl files...

     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling Resources...

     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File

     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...

[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.



-pre-compile:



-compile:

    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\EDEN\Desktop\ORGFAN~1.REM\bin\classes

    [javac] C:\Users\EDEN\Desktop\ORGFAN~1.REM\src\org\faned\remedies\DefaultActivity.java:3: cannot access android.app.Activity

    [javac] bad class file: android\app\Activity.class(android\app:Activity.class)

    [javac] class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0

    [javac] Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

    [javac] import android.app.Activity;

    [javac]                   ^



BUILD FAILED

C:\Users\EDEN\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:716: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Users\EDEN\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:730: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.



Total time: 28 seconds

OPERATION CANCELED
```

I need your help please.

Comment: it seem u have a problem with java_home class path and version, look at the following link maybe help u [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069743/bad-class-file-failed-the-ant-build)

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that your java runtime version is 1.8, but your compiler version (javac) is 1.6. I think you should change the JAVA_HOME to the directory you installed JDK 1.8.

following same topic can help u solve the problem:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069743/bad-class-file-failed-the-ant-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069743/bad-class-file-failed-the-ant-build?lq=1)

[Dreamweaver + Phonegap startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901220/dreamweaver-phonegap-startup?rq=1)[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901220/dreamweaver-phonegap-startup?rq=1)

Comment: MY JAVA_HOME is pointing to jdk 1.8 directory... i checked the java and javac version C:\Users\EDEN>JAVA -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

C:\Users\EDEN>JAVAc -version
javac 1.8.0_25